# JMS Delayed Delivery based on conditional variable(s)

Tags: jms, rabbitmq, activemq-classic

I'm looking for a possibility in any of the more popular message queues (AMPQ, RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ, etc) to conditionally delay the delivery of a message.

For example:

```
System A sends a message(foo, condition = bar.x > 1);
System B sends a message(bar, x = 2)
```

Because the message of System B satisfies the condition set on the Message for System A, the message is unlocked and delivered.

Do such strategies exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of, yes, with RabbitMQ.

You need two things:

1. code that checks the condition - your code, not RabbitMQ code.
2. the Delayed Message Exchange plugin https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/

RabbitMQ does not have the ability to process logic statements or code. But you are already writing code so you can easily do that in your code.

If the condition is true, then send your message to the Delayed Message Exchange. If it is not true, send your message to a normal exchange.